# How to decrypt a PIE file for a game's assets?

Tags: decryption

I want to see the assets for *Garbage Pail Kids: Mad Mike and the Quest for Stale Gum*

I noticed the file was in PIE format. I tried opening them with every program I have, but nothing works; And add insult to injury, the file's encrypted.

What do I do?